# Can carrierwave gem store file on AWS-S3 and local file system at the same time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I use [carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) as my upload gem in rails 3.0.7, and it's really awesome.

I can upload files to local file system(storage :file), and I know how to upload to AWS-S3 as well(storage :fog), but is there any way to upload files to those two destinations at the same form submit? Just in case if local file system or S3 crash or file missing, I still have another copy.

Answer (score -3):

You can try this:

http://carrierwave.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/CarrierWave/Storage/S3.html

```
    CarrierWave.configure do |config|
      config.s3_access_key_id = "xxxxxx"
      config.s3_secret_access_key = "xxxxxx"
      config.s3_bucket = "my_bucket_name"
    end
```

Comment: thanks for your reply :) I know how to config and upload files to S3, but I don't know is there any way to keep a copy in local server while uploading to S3 storage.

Comment: Ok, maybe not quite the answer but you can specify storage per uploader.